# How does X-XSS-Protection work and how would I minimize false positives?

Tags: html, xss

I can't find any detailed documents on how X-XSS-Protection is implemented in the popular browsers. I don't want to use it because I don't know how often it'll have false positives. I'd rather prevent XSS using other methods. However, everyone recommends using X-XSS-Protection.

How exactly does it work? How can I ensure it doesn't block my code?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen an actual definition either, but based on my experience the only thing it does is when there is a `<script>` tag (with some content) in a request parameter that is then reflected back in the response, that javascript will not be run by the browser - and that's it. It's the most basic and straightforward type of reflected XSS only.

I have never in the past seen a false positive on the built in XSS filter. You can be fairly certain that if this feature stops a page from working, that page is indeed vulnerable to XSS by design (eg. relies on Javascript being passed around as parameters - an obviously bad practice that I have actually seen in production applications...)